# jasmine test for $routeprovider resolve in config block

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, route-provider

i have the below in my module config block:

```
var appModule = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$translateProvider', function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

    $routeProvider
        .when('/services/main', {templateUrl: '/services/main/html/main.html', controller: 'MainCtrl', resolve: {
            myVar: function (varService) {
                return varService.invokeService();
            }
        }})
}])
```

**Spec File:**

```
describe("Unit Testing: config - ", function() {

var appModule;
var routes;

beforeEach(function() {
    appModule = angular.module("myApp");
});

it('should test routeProvider', function() {

      inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope) {
          routes = $route;
      });
    }); 
});
```

however, while running the test i am getting the below error:

```
Unit Testing: config -  should test routeProvider FAILED
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider%20%3C-%20%24route
    at Error (native)
```

my karma config includes the angular-route.min.js file. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved with use of angular.mock.module instead of angular.module.

```
appModule = angular.mock.module("myApp");
```

What i found that we should use mock to inject the module and it includes the configuration as well where as module is used to register a newly module. So if one is refering to the module already registered, we should use angular.mock.module.

The documentaion says:

```
This function registers a module configuration code. It collects the configuration information which will be used when the injector is created by inject.
```